Avalonia UI MessageBox freezing
I'm new to Avalonia UI, I'm building simple app and am using MessageBox.Avalonia.
I want to write a service for showing dialogs.
I came up with this:
public class UserDialogService {
    public async Task<ButtonResult> ShowDialog(string title, string message, ButtonEnum button = ButtonEnum.Ok) {
        var dialog = MessageBoxManager.GetMessageBoxStandard(title, message, button);
        var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();
        return result;
    }
}

My problem is that this MessageBox freezes and it's buttons cannot be clicked.
I'm using it like that:
try {
    CreateAppDirectoryIfNotExists();
    Settings = DbSettings.ReadDbSettings();
} catch (Exception exc) {
    if (exc is ConfigurationException) {
        var result = DialogService.ShowDialog("Configuration Error", "The configuration file was not found or was invalid. Should default configuration be written?", ButtonEnum.YesNo).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        if (result == ButtonResult.Yes) {
            Settings = new DbSettings();
            Settings.WriteDbSettings();
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("Failed to setup application.", exc);
}

I've tried to modify the service to launch dialog.ShowAsync() in new thread using Task.Run() but nothing was shown.
What am I doing wrong?
Edit #1:
I've tried using Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync() like this:
public ButtonResult ShowDialog(string title, string message, ButtonEnum button = ButtonEnum.Ok) {
    var dialog = MessageBoxManager.GetMessageBoxStandard(title, message, button);
    return Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(dialog.ShowWindowAsync).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

It didn't help. Nothing is showing up with that approach.

Maybe you're running into some kind of deadlock scenario. Did you try to use Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync instead of Task.Run?

@Janilson Thanks for help, I've updated my question to reflect my attempts to use Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync()

GetAwaiter().GetResult() and there it is

Did you try to use the dispatcher with await? GetAwaiter().GetResult() can also cause deadlocks in UI code

Fixed by adding callback:
public void ShowDialog(string title, string message, ButtonEnum button = ButtonEnum.Ok, Action<ButtonResult>? callback = null) {
    var dialog = MessageBoxManager.GetMessageBoxStandard(title, message, button);
    Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(async () => {
        var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();
        callback?.Invoke(result);
    });
}

Usage:
DialogService.ShowDialog("Title", "Text", ButtonEnum.YesNo, DialogCallback);

private void DialogCallback(ButtonResult result) {
    //React on button clicked
}

